# Java 6.0 | Sqljdbc2.0.jar - com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am trying to connect to SQL DB from Unix server. I have written a Java program for the same and complied in **jre6.0** and using **sqljdbc4-2.0.jar**. But when I try to my jar in Unix server I get the below error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed.".
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1368)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1412)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1058)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:833)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:716)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:841)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:419)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:467)
        at com.tgt.ttedb.TTEDatabaseUpdate.main(TTEDatabaseUpdate.java:31)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.ensureSSLPayload(IOBuffer.java:513)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:570)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:562)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:757)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:745)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.b.a(b.java:215)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.b.a(b.java:18)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:215)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.h(SSLSocketImpl.java:693)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:535)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:710)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1379)
```

Comment: Your Java_6 environment may be forcing you to use a version of the SQL Server JDBC driver that is too old to communicate with current versions of SQL Server or Azure.

Comment: So do i have to use lower version of Sql JDBC driver?

Comment: You'd sooner use a **newer** version of the driver, and you really should no longer target Java 6.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i have no option to move from Java6 , since my prod server has hosted many other applications outside of my control. i will try using next version for sqljdbc